# Generate/ output clock pulse ( C code )

Tags: c, clock, avr, winavr

Im using Ethernut 2.1 B and I need a C program that outputs a clock signal at the timer 1 output B, with other words on  output OCIB. The frequency of the clock signal should be at 1.0 kHz.

Anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in `COM` bits for your timer. For instance, for Timer0 (8-bit), the `COM` bits are set in the `TCCR0` register. Probably the setting you'd be interested in is

```
TCCR0 |= (0<<COM1)|1<<COM0); // Toggle OC0 on compare match
```

This will toggle the OC0 (pin14) line when timer reaches the specified value.

Which timer you use depends on the precision you need: obviosely the 16-bit timers can give you more precise time resolution then the 8-bit timers.

The setting of the registers for your specific frequency (1Khz) depends on the clock speed of your chip, and which timer you are using: the timers use a pre-scaled general clock signal (see table 56 of the datasheet for possible values).  This means that the prescaler settings will depend on your clock speed, and how high you want to count. For most precision you will want to count as high as possible, which means the lowest possible prescaler setting compatible with your timer's maximum value.

As far as where to start, generally, reading the datasheet is a good place, but googling "AVR timer" can also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be based on the [Atmel ATmega 128](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega128.aspx?tab=parameters), so read that CPU's data sheet to figure out how to program the timer hardware.

Not sure if this microcontroller supports directly driving an output from a timer, if it doesn't you're going to have to do it in software from the interrupt service routine.

Comment: yeh, its indeed the Atmel ATmega 128 im using. And yes, I belive i need to do it with a interrupt service routine. Only problem is, I have no clue how the actuall code / syntax would look like. Its part of a school project, and I've no idea where to start!

Comment: You don't need an ISR, just need to set up your timer to toggle an output line.